# Filter double messages from serial

Tags: c#, serialization, filter

I have a variable "value" that contains the last message received from serial port.
I have a multiline textBox "txtOutput" that shows all messages received from serial.
I have also an if statement that filter a specific message to do something that I have placed under the txtOutput_TextChanged in order to get the number in textBox6 to be updated every time there is a new message.

```
    int turns = 0;
    private void txtOutput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (value == 1)
    {
    textBox6.text = turns.ToString();
    turns ++;
    }}
```

I receive the message "1" from the serial port connected to a microprocessor when a microswitch is clicked. The microswitch is monitoring the rotation of a motor that turns very slowly.

My target is to have the above counting system correct before I use it for further implementation of an RPM counter.
The problem I am experiencing right now is that often the microswitch is kept pressed for too long (50 to 100 microseconds) and I receive several consecutive messages(2 or 3)  from serial and I end up counting more turns than real. I have provided some delay on the microcontroller side but I cannot play to much with it otherwise at different speeds I get problems.
**Is there a way to consider only one message received from serial when and if they come consecutively of the same type within, lets say, 1 second timespan?**

I would appreciate some idea and sample snippets.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement code in the microprocessor to send the signal only once. The microswitch is closed a looong time compared to the speed of the micro, so its closed state will be read more than once before it opens. In addition you have to deal with bounce of the microswitch contacts, i.e. there may be several short close/opening states due to mechanical jitter before it stabilizes.

In my view the above is the best solution, deal with the problem at the source.

If you wish to deal with the problem at the receiving end, you have to know all possible frequencies the signal will be received, in real-time, otherwise how can you filter the received signal?

Edit:
So your speed is as follows:
12  rpm, min time between signals:   5 seconds
0.5 rpm, max time between signals: 120 seconds

So when you receive a signal, you know it will take at least 5 seconds before the next GOOD signal to appear.

So this code may filter out false signals:

```
 // code to filter out false signals
    DateTime lastTimeSignalReceived = DateTime.Now;
    double minimumTimeBetweenSignals = 4.9; // 12 rpm = 5 seconds between signals minimum
    int turns = 0;
    private void txtOutput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (value == 1)
        {
            // the if statement is true only if at least 4.9 seconds has past since last signal
            // which should filter out false signals
            if ((DateTime.Now - lastTimeSignalReceived).TotalSeconds > minimumTimeBetweenSignals)
            {
                // at least 4.9 seconds since last signal
                textBox6.text = turns.ToString();
                turns++;

                // set lastTimeSignalReceived to new time
                lastTimeSignalReceived = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well.....I would have not raised the question on this section if I would think that there are more features on the microprocessor language to solve the problem. I think that C# has much more power and resources to manage a specific feature to avoid the described problem.

Comment: The maximum speed of the motor is 12 revolution per minute and the minimum is 0,5 per minute. I am considering to trig a timer for 1 second  when there is a new message and store it in an array. Then after one second take the last message of the array and consider it for plus 1 revolutions, reset the array and wait for the next one. In this way I should be able to filter consecutive messages casued by the long time of the switch closed. Any better idea out there?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement something around the code you suggested. Looks quite nice and may help me also to solve other problems I am experiencing with false messages due to noise during  transients.

Comment: @FeliceM. You are welcome! From your profile I deduce your microprocessor is an Arduino? I have made a home-automation solution around an Arduino Uno, and it works quite well. If you follow the posts on http://arduino.cc/forum then you might find code to deal with contact bounce and sampling signals on ports. I believe I saw a Schmitt trigger as a software routine there, which is great for dealing with contact bounce.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Actualy is an Arduino Uno.